# How to Get max value from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> l_selectedRowobj = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().OrderBy(abc => abc.Index);
l_selectedRowobj.Max();
```

`l_selectedRowobj.Max();` I get a NULL value at this line

I dont want to use List for getting max count like below:

```
List<int> listofRowIndex = new List<int>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in l_selectedRowobj)
{
    listofRowIndex.Add(row.Index);
} 
int maxrowind = listofRowIndex.Max();
```

Comment: Which property of `DataGridViewRow` should be used to determine the max?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the sequence contains any elements first - if it does, then you can get Max value from that sequence by given property:

```
if (l_selectedRowobj.Any())
{
     int max = l_selectedRowobj.Max(row => row.Index);
}
```

or this if you want to assign some value to `max` in case the sequence is empty:

```
int max = l_selectedRowobj.Any() ? l_selectedRowobj.Max(row => row.Index) : 0;
```

Comment: Don't do `l_selectedRowobj.Count() > 0` - do `l_selectedRowobj.Any()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should give your `.Max()` method a clue which property it should use to compare against the others and find the biggest one:

```
int max = l_selectedRowobj.Max(row => row.Index);
```

Comment: Not working showing error "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: Well then I guess the sequence doesn't contain any elements! Are you sure that `l_selectedRowobj` is not empty?