# Is there a method for comparing many int variables to each other?

Tags: c#, variables, comparison

Need to compare ten variables, that provided by user to find the largest one, and display it. Found this:

```
if (new[] { v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10 }.All(x => x == 1))
```

can it work here?

Comment: Do you want the index of the largest one?

Comment: What **exactly** do you want the outcome of your code to be, can you explain?

Comment: The reason I ask is that the naive answer (which you already have an answer providing) is how to find the largest *value*, but maybe you want the *name* of the variable holding the largest value? Additionally, the code you've posted simply checks that all the variables hold the value 1, not the same at all, so can you please clarify what **exactly** it is that you want to accomplish?

Comment: I need to compare 10 integral variables, and display the largest on screen (but only one, for example if there are two biggest numbers only one should be displayed ). User inputs the numbers.

Comment: And by "display the largest on screen", do you mean the largest *value* or the largest *variable*, meaning that "variable" would also identify *which* variable held the largest value? In other words, given your example, if v7 is 987 and that is the highest value, would you want to display 987 or somehow incorporate the string "v7" into your display?

Comment: Just the biggest number.

Comment: Then you should already have your answers by simply refreshing this page.

Comment: Thank You! So many answers in few seconds...

Comment: You can do it using a standard `foreach` loop, where you examine each item in the array, and store it in a variable if it's larger than the current value of the stored item.: `int largestItem = int.MinValue; foreach(var item in items) if (item > largestItem) largestItem = item;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [Linq.Enumerable.Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var max = arr.Max();
```

Check this answer for more info: [How to Get max value from IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492182/how-to-get-max-value-from-ienumerable)

Answer (score 0):

use `System.Linq`

```
var input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var largest = input.Max();
```